# How can I use my slider to adjust the volume of my device?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a slider to adjust the volume of a project I am working on and I cannot find a way to sync the slider to my computers settings. If that is impossible is there a way to convert the value, and divide it so that it would vary between 0.0 and 1 as a decimal to then input it separately into the code?

Here is the volume controller and the place where the music gets recognized.

```
<script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
            const token = '';
            const player = new Spotify.Player({
                name: 'Web Player',
                getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(token); },
                volume: 0.5
            });
```

And here is the slider

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="VolumeValue"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("VolumeValue");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

If you haven't guessed already I am fairly new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was thinking to use the VolumeValue instead of the 0.5 in the first paragraph of code to see if that works

Answer (score 0):

When you're declaring your Spotify `player` variable inside of the `onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady` callback, it's only visible there and you can't call the [setVolume](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/reference/#api-spotify-player-setvolume) method somewhere else to apply slider values.

One option would be to store the player variable in the window object:

```
window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
    window.spotifyPlayer = new Spotify.Player({
        ...
    })
};
```

This would allow you to access it in a slider change event handler:

```
slider.oninput = function() {
    // Assuming you stick to your range 0..100, then this would calculate values 0..1
    window.spotifyPlayer.setVolume(this.value / 100);
}
```

Comment: If I make the slider count from 0.0 to 1.0 I would just delete the " / 100" from the code you provided right?

Comment: Yes; but in that case you may also need to provide a `step` property to the input.

Comment: Yep I got the `step = "0.1"` in place so I should be good on that front